# Setting a math operation for upper and lower half of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, specially pandas, I could not sort it out by my own.

I made up the following dataframe, which represents a way simpler scenario of what I have been working on. So, please, consider the following df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column A': [300,300,450,500,500,750,600,300, 150],
'Column B': [1,1,2,2,3,3,0,2,3], 
'Column C': ["Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_1", 
"Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_5"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column A','Column B', 'Column C'])
```

Which returns the following:

```
         A          B    C  
0       300         1  Value_1
1       300         1  Value_2
2       450         2  Value_3
3       500         2  Value_4
4       500         3  Value_1
5       750         3  Value_2
6       600         0  Value_3
7       300         2  Value_4
8       150         3  Value_5
```

My goal,is by utilising an anonymous function - maybe there are other methods to solve this without anonymous function, however for the more complex situation that I am facing, there is no alternative -, which will take the column A and extract the absolute value of the mean of the lower part minus the mean of the upper part. That means, divide the column into two parts, calculate the mean for each part and then return the absolute value. I am running a for loop doing that for several dataframes, and I want to store that result in another dataframe, hence thats why I am looking for a solution that involves a anonymous function.

For this specific case, the mathematical function that I want to apply would be basically:

```
y = np.absolute((300 + 300 + 450 + 500 + 500)/5 - (750 + 600 + 300 + 150 )/4)
```

Or

```
y = np.absolute((300 + 300 + 450 + 500)/4 - (500 + 750 + 600 + 300 + 150 )/5)
```

Depending where you set the floor/ceil.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized and generalized function dividing your dataframe into two parts and substracting their means.

`numpy` and `pandas` functions used:

- `np.ceil`
- `DataFrame.shape`
- `DataFrame.head`
- `DataFrame.tail`
- `Series.mean`

```
def mean_upper_and_lower(df, val_column):

    n_top = int(np.ceil(df.shape[0] / 2))
    n_bottom = int(df.shape[0] - n_top)

    mean_top = df.head(n_top)[val_column].mean()
    mean_bottom = df.tail(n_bottom)[val_column].mean()

    return abs(mean_top - mean_bottom)
```

**Output**

```
mean_upper_and_lower(df, 'Column A')

40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do it in a single chain in pandas as so:

```
df.groupby(df.index < len(df) // 2)["Column A"].mean().diff().abs()[1]
# 72.5
```

If I unpack it, we create two groups: one `True` where the index is lower than half the length of the index, and one `False` for the upper part. (You can change to lower or equal depending on the definition of lower and upper that you want).

Then we select the column `Column A` and compute the mean.

We then take the difference of the values and take the absolute value.

The scalar value is then accessed by `[1]` of the returned series.

The other possible calculation is:

```
df.groupby(df.index <= len(df) // 2)["Column A"].mean().diff().abs()[True]
# 40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function:-

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column A': [300,300,450,500,500,750,600,300, 150],
'Column B': [1,1,2,2,3,3,0,2,3], 
'Column C': ["Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_1", 
"Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_5"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column A','Column B', 'Column C'])

def foo(c):
    k = math.ceil(len(c)/2)
    return abs(sum(c[:k]/k) - sum(c[k:]/(len(c) - k)))

print(foo(df['Column A'])) # outputs 40.0 here
```